# JTAG Communication Failure in ARRIA 10 FPGA

Tags: communication, intel-fpga, jtag, quartus

Has anyone bricked an ARRIA 10 FGPA (or any FPGA) and successfully unbricked it?

I have an ARRIA 10 that uses an EPCQ-L256 external memory to configure the FPGA. When I uploaded some code, I think I bricked it as I cannot establish communication through JTAG anymore. I have checked the board hardware and all communication channels seem fine.

I found a .jam file from Intel (link below) that seems like a solution to my problem, but I not sure how to approach this.

The command `quartus_jli -c<cable> -aCONFIG_IO a10_unbrick.jam`
must be ran, but from where? I am also confused on what the cable refers to. I am using Quartus Prime (19.1) which comes with system console. but I'm not too familiar with the command line.

My main question is how would I implement that file if the ARRIA10 cannot communicate over JTAG.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can run this command from cmd in /bin folder of you Quartus. (where quartus_jli.exe is)
Also if you run *jtagconfig* you can see number of you cable. (default 1)